# "look forward to keep working" or "keeping working"?

Tags: gerunds, infinitive-vs-gerund

It seems to me that the construction "look forward to" requires the accompanying verb to be in the gerund. But what should one do if there is more than one accompanying verb?

Ludwig found the sentence: "We look forward to keep working with the community on it". Should it be "keeping working"? Or "keep/remain working"?

Answer (score 1):

The rule is the verb after "look forward to" is *always* a gerund. There's no exception if that verb happens to also take a gerund after it, so the correct form is:

> We look forward to **keeping** working...

THAT SAID, having two gerunds in a row sounds awkward to our ears, so try and reword the sentence to avoid this:

> We look forward to **continuing to work**...

Answer (score 0):

correct: **keeping (on) working**

'To' is a preposition 'in look forward to'. It can be followed by a verb in the -**ing** form.

look forward to + (verb + ing)

I look forward to hear**ing** from you soon. We look forward to see**ing** you again.

keep (on) do**ing**= to continue doing

**We look forward to keeping (on) working**...